# taking control back to local from live in a cordova app for android

Tags: php, android, cordova, redirect, payment-gateway

I have a Cordova app on android which is being redirected to a live php page on a server, posting some values. That php page is connecting to the payment gateway and making the payment process. The php page is finally receiving the response from payment gateway as success/failure. Now i want to forward this response back to my cordova application which is running on my device. Is it possible? If yes then how?

Looking forward for the solution as soon as possible

Comment: Have you heard anything about RESTful services ? Check it out if you didn't.

Comment: I got a success somehow using the inappbrowser plugin. Now i just want to close my inappbrowser automatically once the job is done, so that i can get back to the application. This is the point where i am stuck and is not happening. Any clues?

Comment: Post some of your codes, where launch your in-app browser and where you make the http requests.

Comment: $("#payNow").click(function(){
        var param = $("#param");
        var url = 'http://192.168.0.110/paytest/'+param;
        var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', location=yes');
        ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
    });
I just want to close the inAppBrowser automatically once inAppBrowser achieves the url as 'http://192.168.0.110/paytest/done.php'
About sending the required data to the local application, i have taken care of that. All I need to do now is to automatically close this inAppBrowser once the control goes to the url above.
Any clues?

Comment: I cannot read your code like that, and I'm not a JavaScript engineer. If you have anything related with android, let me know. I would go to Native side of In-App browser and close it there.

Comment: I guess i already mentioned its a cordova app. I just want to close the cordova inAppBrowser once the defined url is achieved in the flow. Can anyone help me regarding that?

Comment: You need to customize your in-app browser, from it's native part of code.